# distinguish between X & Y

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to distinguish two things:

- The teams that work in parallel
- The teams that work in series

How should I structure my sentence?

> I want to distinguish between the teams that work in parallel and the one that work in series.

> I want to distinguish between the teams that work in parallel and that in series.

> I want to distinguish between the teams that work in parallel and in series.

Comment: Simple, **"I want to make a distinction between teams that work in parallel and teams that work in series"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to distinguish between the teams that work in parallel and those that work in series.

Or you can try:

I want to distinguish between the teams that work in parallel and the ones that work in series.

Also, you made some mistakes in your question.  This is how it should be written:

I want to write this sentence properly. Firstly, I want to distinguish between two things: a) The teams that work in parallel and b) The teams that work in series.